# htaccess rewrite query string not working as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=3($|&)
RewriteRule ^user/members/profile\.php$ /user/members/profile/id/3?&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

I want the rewrite rules to do two things:

- Remove .php
- change user/members/profile.php?id=3 to user/members/profile/id/3

the query string is being redirected to user/members/profile/id/id=3?id=3

Help!

Comment: you should really tag this with `apache` and `mod-rewrite`

Comment: also you are using `3` as an example, right? you want all URLS to be rewritten that way?

Comment: 3 is just an example. I should've said id=x

Comment: I recommend you have a read through this: https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners . You shouldn't match `3` specifically in your htaccess but use regular expressions

Comment: also useful: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708

Answer (score 0):

So you should match the pattern with regex, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule    ^user/members/profile/id/([0-9]+)/?$    user/members/profile.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

should redirect `user/members/profile.php?id=3` to `user/members/profile/id/3`

Like I mentioned earlier, you can find detailed explanation [here](https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners).
Adding individual rules will be tedious though, might help using a PHP framework that already has better URLs like Laravel or Symfony.

Comment: this rule does not change anything. seems like the regex does not match

Comment: did you try hitting that URL ? `user/members/profile/id/3`

Comment: also did you remove the conditions you had in your post? try with just my two lines

Comment: just edited my answer, pleas try those two lines then try hitting `user/members/profile/id/3`

Comment: yes I have just the two lines you posted. I get a 404 when I go to user/members/profile/id/3

Comment: did you have a look at the links? play with your config until you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/members/profile/id/([0-9]+)/?$ user/members/profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```